# Python For Loop Using Math Operators

Tags: python, for-loop

Ok, I'm in the process of learning Python, and had a quick question about `for` loops. I was wondering if you could use math operators in them, like JavaScript. For example, could I do:

```
for i = 0, i < 5, i++:
    #code here
```

Now, I'm quite aware that Python doesn't support `i++`, and I think it doesn't support the commas either. So if I can do it that way, could you provide a sample.
Thanks

Comment: I'm very tempted to close as "Unclear what you're asking." What's the problem you're trying to solve here? What do you want to do that you're inclined to use this syntax for?

Comment: @jpmc26 I  already got the answer I wanted, but I will amuse you: I was attempting to use a for loop, not in the way up there like I had suggested, but the actual correct way like: `for i in range(x)`. That was working okay, until I started testing it a bit more and realized that if you did it a certain way, it would continue adding on, even though I didn't want it to. I am very new to Python, and aren't the best at JS, but I understand it better than Python, and was just wondering if I could use a for loop like the for loop in JS. I was unaware that I wanted the while loop instead.

Comment: "if you did it a certain way, it would continue adding on" I'm not clear on what this means. Could you be more specific and lay out what you did and what you mean by "adding on"? I have a suspicion that this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and the details at a higher level might suggest an entirely different (and more clear and more robust) answer than a `while` loop. Generally speaking, falling back to rarely used low level constructs because they work like what you're familiar with means there's something you're missing.

Comment: I personally don't believe that this was an XY problem. And I'm a beginner and the while loop was exactly what I needed. Could I have probably explained my question a bit more? Yes, but that's part of me being quite new to this. And to be more specific. Say you were creating a program that counted how many times you typed something in until you hit a certain number of entries. But, if you typed the same thing twice, you wouldn't want it to count as 2 separate entries, so you would want to ignore the second entry. It was like that, but the while loop fixed it perfectly.

Comment: Bottom line is, I got the perfect answer I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a loop is introduced by `for`, does not imply the same behaviour for different languages.

Python's for loop iterates over objects. Something like the C-`for` loop does not exist.

The C `for` loop (`for ( <init> ; <cond> ; <update> ) <statement>`, however, is actually identical to the C code:

```
<init>;
while ( <cond> ) {
    <statement>
    <update>
}
```

So, with the additional information that Python *does* have a `while` loop which behaves like the C-`while` loop, you should now be able to implement something like the C `for` loop in Python. I'll leave that as an exercise:-)

Note: as generating an evenly spaced sequence of integer values is a common case, Python provides the `range()` (Python 3) or `xrange()` (Python 2) function. This does create a `RangeObject` which (basically) yields the next value for a sequence given by start, stop and step arguments.

Comment: Welcome:-) Please delete your comments now (off topic/useless for other readers).

Answer (score 2):

You would use a range loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    #code here
```

If you want to increment in a loop you would use a while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    i += 1
```

To decrement you would use `i -= 1`.

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but is there any other way of doing it, if so how many different ways of doing a for loop are there?

Comment: Yeah @Ryan you may use `for i in range(0, 5, 2)`

Comment: @Ryan, none like you have in your question, if you want to increment you would use a while loop.

Comment: I knew there was another kind of loop, I just couldn't think of it for the life of me. Thank you both

Comment: @Ryan, no worries, there is also no notion of pre and post increment/decrement operators in python etc..

Comment: The use of `xrange` would be the best option prior to Python 3. You can also use `reversed(xrange(5))` if you want to decrement.

Comment: @bnlucas: `reversed` would defy the cause to use `xrange()` actually, as it would first have to get a list to reverse. Why not just use a negative stept and start > end?

Answer (score 1):

## Quick answer

You may use:

```
for i in range(5):
    # code here
```

or

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    i = i + 1 # or i += 1
```

## Boring/pedantic answer

When I was learning Python I disliked the syntax; why should a simple for loop require a second keyword, `range`? The answer, I believe, is due to the fundamental role of the *list* in Python's prescriptive syntax. Repeated annoyances by `range` made me think about how the data were described (or not) before the loop, which in turn led me to think more Pythonically about the design of the data.

Let's say you want to populate a list with the first five perfect squares. You could:

```
squares = []
for i in range(5):
    squares.append(i**2)
```

Alternatively, you could use comprehension:

```
initial_values = range(5) # we've declared the initial values
squares = [i**2 for i in initial_values]
```

Or more compactly:

```
squares = [i**2 for i in range(5)]
```

I routinely encounter problems where there's no *Pythonic* way to write the code, and I end up writing C-like Python (as in the **Quick answer** above). But just as often I find there's a more elegant and readable way to do things, and usually this indicates some imperfections in the antecedent data design.

Comment: You should use `xrange()` in Python2. And it is still different from a counting loop in C or the while you provided. Note there is not necessary a list required, but an iterator. It is just that the list returns an interator on itself during initialization. Also note, that `xrange` (or `range` in Python3) does return a _range object_ which mostly follows the iterator protocol. In general it is better to use generators, as those do not use up memory to create a list first - unless you want to modify the original list.

Comment: Olaf, you're right. Especially if you're iterating over long lists, where memory efficiency might matter. But for short lists use `range`--it's more readable and forward compatible (as an iterator).

Comment: Ok, I will delete my personal comment. You might do the same, as they are of no use for other readers.